How to prevent Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware exceptions from logging to the eventlog
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that's using Serilog to log everything to a file. I'm setting up a global error handler using this in program.cs:
app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions() 
                            {  
                                AllowStatusCode404Response = true, 
                                ExceptionHandlingPath = "/error" 
                            });

I've seen several articles saying that adding this to the app.settings should stop the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware from being logged:
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "None"
    }
}

However, anytime an exception is thrown, it gets logged to my Serilog file as well as this showing up in the EventLog:

Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
EventId: 1
SpanId: 436cfbe67205ba87
TraceId: 74e004a439b069b40d366019bc429ac3
ParentId: 0000000000000000
ConnectionId: 0HN6V3VNU8A4U
RequestId: 0HN6V3VNU8A4U:00000001
RequestPath: /QAReleaseAhead/Profile
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

What am I doing wrong here?

You could add following configuration to avoid this logging.
builder.Logging.AddEventLog(settings =>
{
    settings.LogName = "MyAppLog"; // Optional custom log name
}).AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware", LogLevel.None);`
``


I still see the exceptions in the application eventlog.

I have succeeded to achieve what you want by adding:
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
    .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.Properties["SourceContext"].ToString().Contains("Microsoft.AspNetCore"))
    .CreateLogger();

Of course, you need to enhance the logic to account for when SourceContext won't be in the dictionary and if there's better way to check if event contains Microsoft.AspNetCore namespace.
Here's minimal example for ASP.NET Core with minimal APIs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
    .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.Properties["SourceContext"].ToString().Contains("Microsoft.AspNetCore"))
    .CreateLogger();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSerilog();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapGet("/", () =>
{
    throw new Exception("my exception");
});

app.Run();


When I try your example, I still see exceptions in the Application EventLog:  Category: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware

I tried both approaches mentioned above to no avail.  I was able to get rid of these application eventlog entries by adding the following into program.cs.
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();

